# how to convert number into date using hive?

Tags: hive, apache-pig

I have a table with three columns: *number of ten digits, time and name*.

```
1473522179,18:39,sukesh
1474209006,9:16,syam
1473820431,7:40,ram
```

How can i convert first column into date with GMT timeZone using hive and pig?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ToDate](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#datetime-functions).Assuming your relation has fields f1,f2,f3

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(f1),f2,f3;
```

Hive

```
SELECT from_unixtime(f1),f2,f3 from A
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using from_unixtime, for example your first column date is:

```
to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(1473522179),"GMT")
```

**2016-09-10 18:42:59.0**

Comment: Is worth to mention that without specifying the second argument you get automatically the 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' format

Comment: That is right, I didn't noticed that, then it would be select `to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(1473522179),"GMT")`